# It's possible to restrict access with PAM based on groups?

Tags: centos, permissions, users, pam

I was wondering if it's possible to create a rule in `/etc/security/time.conf` in which you restrict users to log in not just by username but instead by the group they belong to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pam_group` module has a similar configuration file, [group.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/group.conf), which lets you restrict groups with a certain time definition.